# Simple preloader for tile state - Set view property from controller?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I want to add a simple preloader for my ajax request for each tile in my list. I have a list of items in my model but I only want to show the preloader in the matching tile. At the moment my example shows the preloader for all tiles probably because I am setting isLoading on the controller when I really want to set it on the view that triggered it.

So my question is how do I set isLoading to only the view that called the corresponding controller to prevent the Preloading!! text from appearing in all tile list items?

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
<ul>
  {{#each item in model}}
    <li>{{partial 'tile'}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="_tile">
    TILE: {{item}}

    <button {{action "search"}}>Load me</button>

    {{#if isLoading}}
      <h1>Preloading!!</h1>
    {{/if}}
  </script>

App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'];
    }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    actions: {
        search: function(){

            if(this.get('isLoading')) {
                return;
            }

            this.set('isLoading', true);

            var that = this;

            //Ajax stuff here
            setTimeout(function(){
                that.set('isLoading', false);
            }, 3000);
        }
    }
});

App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
    isLoading: false,
    actions:{
        search: 'search'
    }
});
```

[Link to JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Malcr001/Wk5UU/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `partial` helper will not create a separate view for each tile 
(documenation http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/). So the `isLoading` variable will be single and common to all tile instances. This is the reason that preloading appears for all of the tiles.

To solve this issue there plenty of approaches, i will demonstrate two using the `{{view}}` helper and `{{render}}` helper.

**{{view}} helper**

In order to use this helper a view needs to be created, along with the following steps.

1. rename template of partial to `tile`
2. replace `{{partial}}` helper with `{{view}}` helper
3. create a `TileView` that will be rendered by the `{{view}}` helper
4. i suggest to move the ui logic related to showing *loading* to the `view`, also using a callback for hiding the *loading*, and let the `controller` clearly handle only the ajax/business logic part
5. modify the template of the view to check the view's variable by setting `view.isLoading` and also set the `target` of the `{{action}}` helper to the `view` in order to show the *loading* before the event is delegated to the `controller` by calling `send`.

http://jsfiddle.net/8A8DK/

**hbs**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
    <ul>
      {{#each item in model}}
        <li>{{view App.TileView}}</li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="tile">
    TILE: {{item}}

    <button {{action "search" target="view"}}>Load me</button>

    {{#if view.isLoading}}
      <h1>Preloading!!</h1>
    {{/if}}
  </script>
```

**js**

```
    App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    actions: {
        search: function(callback){
            //Ajax stuff here
            setTimeout(function(){

                callback();
            }, 3000);
        }
    }
});

App.TileView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName:'tile',
    isLoading: false,
    actions:{
        search:function(){
            var self = this;
            this.set('isLoading', true);
            this.get("controller").send("search",function(){
                self.set('isLoading',false);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

**{{render}} helper**

By using this helper it is possible to have a separate instance of `ObjectController` for each view created to execute logic that is related only to the scope of the view, instead of placing it within an `ArrayController`

*(note: having a separate `ObjectController` may also be possible by using the previous solution along with the `itemController` of the `ArrayController` 
http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html )*

1. rename template of partial to `tile`
2. replace `{{partial}}` helper with `{{render}}` helper
3. create a `TileView` that will be rendered by the `{{render}}` helper
4. create a `TileController` that will be used by the `{{render}}` helper
5. i suggest to move the ui logic related to showing *loading* to the `view`, also using a callback for hiding the *loading*, and let the `controller` clearly handle only the ajax/business logic part
6. modify the template of the view to check the view's variable by setting `view.isLoading` and also set the `target` of the `{{action}}` helper to the `view` in order to show the *loading* before the event is delegated to the `controller` by calling `send`.

http://jsfiddle.net/aXL8R/

**hbs**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
    <ul>
      {{#each item in model}}
        <li>{{render 'tile' item}}</li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="tile">
    TILE: {{item}}

    <button {{action "search" target="view"}}>Load me</button>

    {{#if view.isLoading}}
      <h1>Preloading!!</h1>
    {{/if}}
  </script>
```

**js**

```
App.TileController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions: {
        search: function(callback){

            //Ajax stuff here
            setTimeout(function(){
                callback();
            }, 3000);
        }
    }
});

App.TileView = Ember.View.extend({
    isLoading: false,
    actions:{
        search: function(){
            var self = this;
            this.set('isLoading', true);
            this.get("controller").send("search",function(){
                self.set('isLoading',false);
            });
        }
    }
});
```